# SVG to Drawable

Tags: java, android, svg, изображения, android-drawable

Я в рантайме создаю SVG картинку. Вопрос - как мне этот SVG передать в метод, который принимает объект `Drawable`?

Картинка у меня трехцветная pie-диаграмма, но угол каждого сектора определяется в рантайме и в ресурсы такое не упакуешь.

Если SVG здесь мешает, то могу ее рисовать сам на какой-нибудь канве. Но в конечном счете нужен Drawable

Comment: А какой тип у вас у вашего программно созданного SVG? Если Bitmap - то можно так: `Drawable mDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб сейчас это XML. Строка или какой-нибудь Stream

Comment: @ЮрийСПб допустим я возьму VectorDrawable и буду формировать не svg, а android-xml. Но все равно, я не вижу как в него загрузить данные

Comment: Нашел [библиотеку](https://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/) которая умеет InputStream/String преобразовывать в Picture, а потом его скормить в PictureDrawable

Comment: Вот еще нашел у Drawable статические методы createFromStream и createFromXml. Нужно посмотреть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод [Drawable.createFromStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable#createFromStream(java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String)) мне не удалось заставить работать. И на SVG, и на XML он возвращал `null` без дополнительных пояснений.

Поэтому была взята библиотека [AndroidSVG](https://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/) и с помощью нее задача решилась в три строчки

```java
SVG svg = SVG.getFromString(svgStr);
Picture pic = svg.renderToPicture();
Drawable drawable = new PictureDrawable(pic);
```

Comment: Drawable.createFromStream принимает скомпилированный xml файл а не текстовый, о существовании SVG этому методу ничего не известно. В общем случае на ваш вопрос можно ответить: "никак".

Comment: @Style-7 Что за скомпилированный xml файл? Я брал xml из папки drawable и тоже получил null

Comment: все ресурсы там уже скомпилированы. это не текст.